# Bootstrap 3 datepicker - minDate and maxDate

Tags: javascript

http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Hi

I am trying to use the min max date options but not sure how to use it as the documentation doesn't provide example code.

I found on stackoverflow that you can do this:

minDate: moment()

But that throws an error that moment is not defined.

I am guessing it can't find the moment.js which is included on the page otherwise the plugin wouldn't work.

What I am trying to achieve is to disable 10 days before the current day and show 30 days from the current day.

Thanks

```js
Here is the code (I have removed everything except whats important to simply show the code):

window[ns] = window[ns] || {};
(function ($, moment, app) {
    'use strict';

    // Private Methods
    var nameSpace = 'global',
        globalDataObject = null,

       
        notifyRenderCallbacks = function (pageName) {

            if ($('.js-calendar').length) {
                $('.js-calendar').datetimepicker({
                    format: 'DD MMMM YYYY',
                    dayViewHeaderFormat: 'MMMM YYYY',
                    icons: {
                        next: 'icon icon-chevronright',
                        previous: 'icon icon-chevronleft'
                    },
                    enabledDates: moment().add(30, 'days')
                });

            }

        },



    // If this module requires global data

    app.register(nameSpace, initialize);


}(jQuery, moment, window[ns] || {}));
```

Comment: You can do something with moment.js but since my code keeps throwing error when using moment()

Comment: Does anyone know of an sites which has examples on how to use Bootstrap 3 datepicker?

Comment: As you can see, I am using moment (in this example for enabledDates) but I keep getting error that moment is not defined. I checked on my dev console log and I am able to use moment function perfectly fine there.

Comment: use pickTime: false

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To answer my question. The framework used required you to add moment to a config file otherwise it would not allow to use http://momentjs.com/ or any other JS - spoke to the person who set up the framework and they did it for security reasons.

Kasun's answer is correct but a better way to do this is to use Moment.js since datetimepicker is using this JS.

So to answer the 2nd part which is to disable 10 days before the current day and show 30 days from the current day you need to set the options as below. I didn't need to do the 10 days before but wanted only a set number of days to be available to select. I've added comments to make things clear but they shouldn't be there.

```
$mydatepicker.datetimepicker({
    minDate: moment(), // Current day
    maxDate: moment().add(30, 'days'), // 30 days from the current day
    viewMode: 'days',
    format: 'DD MMMM YYYY',
    dayViewHeaderFormat: 'MMMM YYYY',
});
```

What the above will do is enable all the days between minDate and maxDate.

You could also directly enter the date range:

```
$mydatepicker.datetimepicker({
    minDate: moment("12/01/2015"),
    maxDate: moment("12/30/2015"),
    viewMode: 'days',
    format: 'DD MMMM YYYY',
    dayViewHeaderFormat: 'MMMM YYYY',
});
```

And this will disable all days before and after the dates you entered into moment().

This is not part of the question but I wanted to display the current day in the input value when the calendar loaded but it wouldn't, instead it would show the placeholder text. I think its because of the use if minDate so I simply used jQuery to replace the value of the input.

```
$datepickerInput.val(moment());
```

Comment: I think my answer is more dynamic than yours.

Comment: Hi Kasun, sorry you must have not understood what I wrote above. You can do everything out of the box so your method means someone writing unnecessary code. Read my code, which isn't really my code, its really the code of the plugin with my values, and then compare it with yours and then provide details why its more dynamic. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

```
var todayDate = new Date().getDate();

$('#element').datetimepicker({
  timepicker:false,
  formatDate:'Y/m/d',
  minDate: new Date(),
  maxDate: new Date(new Date().setDate(todayDate + 30))
});
```

By using this example you can give option to user to select date between today and next 30 days without using momentjs. You can provide value of minDate and maxDate accoording to you. For an example if you want to give options in between last 30 days to next 30 days, so set

```
minDate: new Date(new Date().setDate(todayDate - 30))
maxDate: new Date(new Date().setDate(todayDate + 30))
```

Comment: Please provide in your code how to set the value of the variable "todayDate"

Answer (score 0):

Just give this way, using JavaScript Date Object:

```
minDate: (new Date()).getDate()
```

Answer (score 0):

**For disable**

```js
$("#editreservation_to").datetimepicker({minDate:-1,maxDate:-2}).attr('readonly','readonly');
```

**For Enable**

```js
$("#editreservation_to").datetimepicker({minDate:false,maxDate:false}).removeAttr('readonly');
```