# Change date time mindate and maxdate based on dropdown option

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datetimepicker

there are 3 options in my dropdown box
if option 1st is selected min date should be 2013 and max date will be 2015
if option 2nd is selected then min date should be 2009 and max date will be 2014
if option 3rd is selected then min date will be 2005 and max date will be 2008
 here is my application screenshot

[image]

eg. if user selects LKG then min date will be 2013 and max will be 2015 so that user can select date between this.
i have tried code something like this

```
function chk()
{
    var sname = $('#app_for_class').find(":selected").text();
    if(sname==='LKG')
    {
         $('#date').datetimepicker({
        minDate:'2013-01-1',
        maxDate:'2015-11-30',

    });

    }


}
```

here is html code

```
 <select class="form-control" onclick="chk()"  style="margin-left: 5px" name="app_for_class" id="app_for_class">
            <option name="app_for_class" value="LKG">LKG</option>
            <option name="app_for_class" value="UKG">UKG</option>
            <option name="app_for_class" value="1st">1st Standard</option>


 </select>

<input class="form-control" type="date" required="true"  id="date" name="date" style="margin-left: 20px;width: 210px">
```

Comment: I think there is a Spelling mistake in your form. It should be "Child's Name" not "Chield's Name"

Comment: whats error in console?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datetimepicker is not a function
    at chk (Dashboard:451)
    at HTMLSelectElement.onclick (Dashboard:85)

Comment: Try using `moment.js` library as pointed out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34071003/bootstrap-3-datepicker-mindate-and-maxdate/34071057) answer.

Comment: try using datepicker() instead

Comment: same errorokeyur

Comment: @treolandix will check using mement.js

Comment: maxDate:'2015-11-31' is this date possible month 11 contains 31 days I dont think so?

Comment: hmm your right.

Comment: try this https://jsfiddle.net/95j35vdt/11/

Answer (score 0):

I have modified your jQuery function a bit-

```
function chk(){
    var sname = $('#app_for_class').find(":selected").text();
    if(sname=='LKG'){
        $('#date').datetimepicker({
            minDate: new Date(2013, 1 - 1, 1),
            maxDate: new Date(2015, 11 - 1, 30)
        });
    }
}
```

Next you should capture the `onChange()` event of your drop down list and call the `chk()` function-

```
$("#app_for_class").change(function() {
    chk();
});
```

And your HTML should not contain `onClick`-

```
<select class="form-control" style="margin-left: 5px" name="app_for_class" id="app_for_class">
```