# When I restrict Past date it also restrict past time

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, bootstrap-4

I am using this bootstrap daterangepicker. When I restrict the past date its also restrict past time.How can I get Past time in  daterangepicker.
Is there another way to restrict only past date insted of using minDate function?

I am using below Code

```
$(function() {
  $('input[name="datetimes"]').daterangepicker({
    timePicker: true,
    minDate: new Date(),
    startDate: moment().startOf('hour'),
    endDate: moment().startOf('hour').add(32, 'hour'),
    locale: {
      format: 'M/DD hh:mm A'
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41719464/14973743) is related to your need.

Comment: When I use restrict only for date that not allow past date its also affect to past time. – 
Anand Sowmithiran

Answer (score 0):

Since you are setting the `minDate` option to "new Date()", which results in the **exact time** (till accuracy of hh:mm:ss) when browser executes that line, so the date-time picker does *not* allow any time before that moment :-) [No pun intended].

If you want to restrict the `minDate` to any time from today, then, set it like so,

```
  minDate : moment().startOf('day')
```

This sets the minimum selectable time as '12:00' today. You will not be able to select yesterday or any prior day.
You don't need to set the startDate and endDate properties.